# Return custom object from onError() of Rx java Android instead of throw-able object

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java2, rx-android

I am new to RX Java. While implementing Rx java with Retrofit i found i am getting throw-able object in my `doOnError(){}`

But what i want my doOnError() of RX Java should return ErrorBase() -> that is my custom class.  instead of throwable.

it will help me to handle error at central. i will pass my throw-able object to my ErrorBase class where i have handled custom messages.

Below is `doOnError()`. Where i want to return ErrorBase object

```
apiInterface.getLoginDetails(auth)
        .doOnNext {
           //LoginResponse
        }
        doOnError{
        return ErrorBase(throwable)
          }
```

Code of other classes.

**Api Interface class**

```
interface ApiInterface {

@POST("login")
fun getLoginDetails(@Header(Constants.AUTHORIZATION) auth: String): Observable<LoginResponseModel>
}
```

**LoginRepository**

```
class LoginRepository @Inject constructor(private val apiInterface: ApiInterface,
                                      val utils: Utils) {


fun getLoginDetails(auth: String): Observable<LoginResponseModel> {

    return apiInterface.getLoginDetails(auth)
            .doOnNext {
            }
            .doOnError {
              //Right now having throw-able object
            }

}
}
```

**ErrorBase**

```
class ErrorBase(private val throwable: Throwable) {

private var message: String?
private var statusCode: Int


init {
    statusCode = getStatusCode()
    message = getMessage()
}

private fun getStatusCode(): Int {
    if (throwable is HttpException) {
        val exception = throwable
        return exception.code()
    }
    return -1
}

private fun getMessage() =
        when (throwable) {
            is IOException -> "Something Went Wrong"
            is UnknownHostException -> "No internet connectivity"
            is SocketTimeoutException -> "Slow Internet connectivity"
            else -> throwable.message
        }
}
```

**LoginvViewModel**

```
class LoginViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val loginRepository: LoginRepository) : ViewModel() {
private val TAG = this.javaClass.name
private var loginResult: MutableLiveData<LoginResponseModel> = MutableLiveData()
private var loginError: MutableLiveData<String> = MutableLiveData()
private var loginLoader: MutableLiveData<Boolean> = MutableLiveData()

private lateinit var disposableObserver: DisposableObserver<LoginResponseModel>

fun loginResult(): LiveData<LoginResponseModel> {
    return loginResult
}

fun loginError(): LiveData<String> {
    return loginError
}

fun loginLoader(): LiveData<Boolean> {
    return loginLoader
}


private fun getLoginData(auth: String) {
    loginLoader.postValue(true)
    initLoginObserver()
    loginRepository.getLoginDetails(auth)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .debounce(400, MILLISECONDS)
            .subscribe(disposableObserver)
}

private fun initLoginObserver() {
    disposableObserver = object : DisposableObserver<LoginResponseModel>() {
        override fun onComplete() {

        }

        override fun onNext(loginDetails: LoginResponseModel) {
            loginResult.postValue(loginDetails)
            loginLoader.postValue(false)
        }

        override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
            loginError.postValue(e.message)
            loginLoader.postValue(false)
        }
    }
}

fun disposeElements() {
    if (null != disposableObserver && !disposableObserver.isDisposed) disposableObserver.dispose()
}

fun loginClicked() {
    getLoginData("auth")
}}
```

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, `doOnError` isn't aimed to transform/return some data, but helps to handle side-effects like logging.

Second thing, `ErrorBase` doesn't fit well together with `LoginResponseModel` cause they don't have any common parent.

Thus, I suggest you following solution:

1. Create one base class for your response:

   ```
   sealed class LoginResponse {

       class Result( ..your data here.. ) : LoginResponse()

       class Error( ... ) : LoginResponse()
   }
   ```
2. Make function return `LoginResponse` and do following changes:

   ```
   fun getLoginDetails(auth: String): Observable<LoginResponse> {
       return apiInterface.getLoginDetails(auth)
                  .map { data -> LoginResponse.Result(data) }
                  .onErrorReturn { throwable -> LoginResponse.Error(throwable) }
   }
   ```
3. Now both results have one common parent and you can use `getLoginDetails` in the following way:

   ```
   fun doRequest() {
        loginRepository.getLoginDetails(auth)
            .subscribe { result ->
                 when (result) {
                      is LoginResponse.Result -> //do something with result
                      is LoginResponse.Error -> //do something with error
                 }
            }
   }
   ```

Some explanation.

- `onErrorReturn` does exactly what you need - returns your custom value in case if error occurs
- If you don't add `LoginResponse` you have to make `Observable<Any>` which is loosely typed and doesn't really well describes your interface.
- Making `LoginResponse` **sealed** allows to check only 2 cases whether emitted data is `Result` or `Error`. Otherwise Kotlin compiler forces you to add additional `else` branch

**Update** In case if you need to do same thing in multiple places you can go with this:

```
sealed class Response<T> {

    data class Result<T>(val result: T) : Response<T>()

    data class Error<T>(val throwable: Throwable) : Response<T>()
}

fun getLoginDetails(auth: String): Observable<Response<LoginResponseModel>> {
    return apiInterface.getLoginDetails(auth)
               .map<Response<LoginResponseModel>> { data -> Response.Result(data) }
               .onErrorReturn { throwable -> LoginResponse.Error(throwable) }
}

..and somewhere in your code..

fun handleResponse(response: Response<LoginData>) {
    when (response) {
        is Response.Result -> response.result
        is Response.Error -> response.throwable
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer @hluhovskyi. 
i have one doubt. if i have to call another api from different screen.
in that case i require same Error class but different response model.
so if i follow with this approach i need to create separate error class for each response?

Comment: There are various ways here. You can create different responses with different errors for each call. You can make abstraction like some interface over them. You can create generic `Response<T>`  and use it everywhere for wrapping your data. Personally, I like last one the most so I will update answer. But in any case it is up to you and up to your business needs.

Comment: i am sorry but i am itching my head, how to fit this Response class with LoginRespone "Model" class 

1. Do every Single response class(LoginResponse) will inherit Response class
2.  As my ErrorBase class is different how to link with Error class.
i am unable to digest this

Comment: You don't need to inherit, you do need to **wrap**. Every call should return `Single<Response<Something>>`. In your case it will be `Single<Response<LoginResponseModel>>`. And by `Response.Error` i mean `ErrorBase` but named and placed in another way.

Comment: @ hluhovskyi  i did the same but 
apiInterface.getLoginDetails(auth)
                .map { it ->
                    Result(it)
                }
                .onErrorReturn {
                    Error(it)
                }
its not working . in case of Error(data) it giving me error type inference failed.Expected type mismatch and asking me return expression required in function with block body

Comment: having error in 
data -> Response.Result(data)

required:  Response<LoginResponseModel>!
found: Response.Result<Response<LoginResponseModel>>